# how to call an alert after an option is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, select

I am trying to make a username, ID and password linking form but i need to make sure that the program recognises that a username has been selected.
This is what I have done:

```
var usernameBox = document.getElementsByName("uop");
    usernameBox.onclick = function(){
        if (usernameBox.options[usernameBox.selectedIndex].value == false){
        alert("Please choose your username");
    }
    }
```

This does not work for me and I am a beginner to javascript so I'm not very familiar with a lot of the concepts but that's what learning is for right.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour to get a better understanding about https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Another good read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions?. Afterwards, please edit your question to add all the relevant code

Comment: Can you please post your HTML code? It will be helpful for us.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the `onchange` attribute in the HTML itself, which calls a function in the JavaScript.
Heres a example

```html
<input type="text" onchange="inputOnChange()" id="input-username"/>
<script> 
function inputOnChange() {
   let usernameinput = document.getElementById("input-username");
   let username = usernameinput.value;
   // do whatever u want with the username now
   console.log(username);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could update a variable everytime the 'select' element is changed, then show the alert. You can use the `username` variable wherever you would like. Here is how you could do this...

```
var usernameBox = document.getElementById("uop");
let username = usernameBox.value;

usernameBox.onchange = (e) => {
  username = e.target.value;
  alert(username);
}
```